# Getting issue in reading csv file from asset in twilio function

Tags: twilio, twilio-api, twilio-twiml

```html
 var fs = require('fs');
        let fileName = 'file.csv';
        let file = Runtime.getAssets()[fileName].path;
        let text = fs.readFileSync(file);
            console.log('Your file contents: ' + text);
```

```
{
    "message": "Cannot read property 'path' of undefined",
    "name": "TypeError",
    "stack": "TypeError: Cannot read property 'path' of undefined\n    at Object.exports.handler (/var/task/handlers/ZFbf83ef45896ffe95e21dd028385c58ec.js:12:49)\n    at Object.exports.handler (/var/task/node_modules/enigma-lambda/index.js:310:10)\n    at Runtime.exports.handler (/var/task/enigma.js:17:9)\n    at Runtime.handleOnce (/var/runtime/Runtime.js:66:25)"
}
```

I have added the file to asset and trying to get that csv from asset into the twilio function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tested out your code and it works for me.

Did you upload the file.csv as a [private asset](https://www.twilio.com/docs/runtime/assets#private-assets)?

Answer (score 1):

It's about to look that `file.csv` is public asset file.
`Runtime.getAssets()` can only get private asset file's info.
So if `file.csv` is public asset file, `Runtime.getAssets()[fileName]` return no asset object and you cannnot get `path` value from that's result.

Answer (score 0):

I had a silly problem by not adding the / in front of my file name when i was referencing it in the code, which also lead to the undefined issue. This is when you upload your  asset in the Asset or Functions beta ui.

```
let fileName = '/filename.csv';
let assetFile = Runtime.getAssets()[fileName].path;
const assetContent = fs.readFileSync(assetFile).toString('utf-8');
```